# Inserting parent/child rows in Hibernate with autoincrement index throws error

Tags: scala, hibernate

I have the following Hibernate classes in Scala, where one `Group` has many `Items`. Note that the @Id of the `Group` class has an autoincrement annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
class Item extends Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="group_sk", nullable=false)
    var group: Group = _

    @Id
    var index: Int = _

    var name: String = _

    def canEqual(a: Any) = a.isInstanceOf[Item]

    override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
        that match {
            case that: Item => that.canEqual(this) && this.hashCode == that.hashCode
            case _ => false
     }

    override def hashCode: Int = {
        val prime = 31
        var result = 1
        result = prime * result + group.sk;
        result = prime * result + index
        return result
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "group_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="group_generator", 
    sequenceName = "GroupSeq", allocationSize = 1)    
    var sk: Int = _

    @Column(name = "group_name")
    var name: String = _

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="group_sk") 
    var items: java.util.List[Item] = _
}
```

I try to insert one group with a related item, where both the `Group` should have an auto incremented Id:

```
    session.beginTransaction
    val group = new Group
    group.name = "Group name"
    group.items = new java.util.ArrayList[Item]()

    val item1 = new Item
    item1.group = group
    item1.index = 1
    item1.name = "Item 1"
    group.items.add(item1)

    session.save(group)
    session.getTransaction.commit
```

The exception I get is

> Caused by: javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update
>   returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0;
>   expected: 1

And the Hibernate sql log shows:

```
Hibernate: select GroupSeq.nextval from dummy
Hibernate: insert into groups (group_name, sk) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update items set group_sk=? where index=? and group_sk=?
```

Note that the last update statement doesn't make sense because you won't update the value of `group_sk` where the column is also in the condition. Moreover, there's no insert statement of the `items` table.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set cascade type on your OneToMany relationship to tell Hibernate how to mange Items collection of the Group class. So for example something like this should work:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="group_sk") 
var items: java.util.List[Item] = _
```

Comment: This is the Scala syntax: `@OneToMany(cascade=Array(CascadeType.ALL))`